# can client explicitly destroy stateless session bean?

Tags: lifecycle, stateless-session-bean

The ejb container controls the bean life-cycle, and normally client side does not need to care bean life-cycle. But I still wonder if there is a way to explicitly remove/destroy a stateless session bean instance from Method-Ready-Pool?

For stateful session bean we can call one method annotated @remove to remove that stateful session bean. But it's not for stateless session bean.